# Unable to skip to next iteration in for-loop statement

Tags: python, loops, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I use Selenium to scrap a website and get the related data. I wrote the following script:

```
def scrap_understat(bot_function):
   init_db_connection()
   init_browser('firefox')

   for i in range(7240, 8000):
        try:
            driver.get('https://understat.com/player/' + str(i))
            while not wait_for_element(driver, By.ID, 'header'):
                driver.get('https://understat.com/player/' + str(i))
            time.sleep(1)
            if try_find_Element(driver, By.CLASS_NAME, 'error-code') is not None:
                continue
            player_name = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'header-wrapper').text
            current_team = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'breadcrumb').find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'li')[-2].text
            data = get_player_data(player_name, current_team)
            save_data(data)

        except Exception as ex:
            log_this(ex)
            print(str(ex))
```

However, the script stops by the first 'error':
https://understat.com/player/7245

Clearly, this page contains the error-code class. If I inspect the page I see the following

*span class="error-code">404*

whereas, for example, on https://understat.com/player/7245 this class is not present. I use the `continue`-command to go to the next iteration. However, the browser freezes on https://understat.com/player/7245. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your code never reaches the `continue`, it gets hung in an infinite loop of reloading the page until `'header'` is present.

Comment: Your code is full of custom methods. That definitely not helps us to understand your issue... What is `wait_for_element`, `try_find_Element`...? What should those methods return? What is your desired output?